# HTA - VBScript - Install program but wait for installation to complete

Tags: vbscript, hta

If you could give my a hand that would be great?

I have a HTA file nothing to fancy its to install a few programs one by one

I have been reading in a few places on how to wait for installation to complete 
then install the next program but none make sense to me for what i want, also 
they are saying to use wscript.sleep that would be great but it doesnt work in a HTA right ?

I have firefox, utorrent, symantec antivirus, adobe reader, office 2003 (packaged with KEY already)
and a few others.

i want to find switches to install silently but thats not important if this code someone is willing to show me works...

I hope I make sense ?

If you can help me it would be great ?

Cheers Pavle.

Comment: Even in a browser control you should be able to create the shell object using CreateObject("WScript.Shell"). From that object you have access to the Run, Exec or ShellExecute methods. As far as running these packages siilently goes, you will need to consult with the individual vendors. if they are MSI packages, then use msiexec.exe with the /qn! parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You might find something useful in my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742182/128427) to this question: [How to get an HTA to restart itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599384/how-to-get-an-hta-to-restart-itself)

It uses a VBScript helper to wait for a process to end (the HTA itself) then restarts the HTA. You could modify the vbscript instead to wait for a specific process to end (one of your installers), then return control to the HTA which starts the next installer and calls the wait script again.

I don't think an HTA can call the WScript.Sleep routine, but there are the setTimeout and setInterval methods in HTA that call a routine after X seconds, or repeatedly call a routine after every X seconds until cancelled. You can use these to check periodically if a process is still running (using WMI Win32_Process as I show in my other answer).

To process a list of items like this, instead of using a loop to go through a list and pause after each item, you have a central state-machine routine that calls itself every so often to advance the system.

```
'!! extremely "pseudo" pseudo-code follows

sub StartSystem()
    state = "next program"
    list = list of programs to install
    AdvanceSystem() 
end sub

sub AdvanceSystem()

    if state = "next program"

        if more items in list
            start next installer
            remove from list (or increment an index)

            set state to "check program"
        else
            set state to "done"

    if state = "check program"

        use WMI to see if process is still running
        if no
            state = "next program"

    if state <> "done"
        setInterval(AdvanceSystem, 5000) ' call again in 5 seconds

end sub


' then somewhere in your HTA interface have a button to start things off
buttonClick = StartSystem()
```

Using an arrangement like this you may not even need to run a separate VBScript to check the process and sleep. Also, with this kind of incremental process, you can send output to a DIV somewhere so the user can see progress, whereas when processing things in a loop, output doesn't show up until the whole process has finished. After each pass through AdvanceSystem, the control returns to the HTA level and the system can update itself.

Let me know if you need a more specific example, I'll try to write something up.